# Использование, связка бинов в Java

Tags: java, netbeans, xhtml

У меня есть example.xhtml, я не знаю как правильно его заполнить, так как NetBeans предлагает один вариант, а видео, где все работает, заполняют по-другому.
**Netbeans:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

В то время как в "обучалке" идет использование тегов по типу:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.text}">
</h:head>
```

У меня это подчеркивает.
Далее, есть класс **exampleBean:**

```
package webapp;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named
public class exampleBean {
    private String text = "Text";
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    } 
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно связать этот класс с xhtml-файлом, и чего для этого не хватает.

P.S. Проект собираю через maven, через командную строку, сервер работает, страницы загружает.

Comment: чем больше я пытаюсь разобраться, тем более мне кажется, что этот класс не следует называть бином

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что все работает хорошо и проблема только в подсветке синтаксиса в Netbeans?

Comment: @defaultlocale нет, не работает в этом и проблема)

Comment: в видео у него в идеи все работает, а у меня ошибку в xhtml файле, а если и работает, то не подключает бин

Comment: могу проект прислать прислать, если это поможет)

Comment: какой блин смысл отдавать 50 репутации, если все равно никто не отвечает(

Comment: дайте ссылку на проект, так будет проще и быстре...

Comment: Поменяйте название класса на `ExampleBean` или явно укажите в `@Named` id бина

Comment: И мне интересно, какое отношение к Вашему вопросу имеет тег `netbeans`?

Comment: @notaProgrammer именно netbeans создает xhtml не такой, как надо

Comment: @notaProgrammer  то есть название бина объязательно с большой буквы?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проект и дайте ссылку на туториал, пожалуйста